# Query regarding Electric Potential and Electric field intensity

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism

We have a relation between Electric field(E) and potential(V) as

```
E = -∇V and V = -Integral (E)dl
```

In such case, V have to be equal to -E.D ::: V = -E.D but in most cases we use V=E.D. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it like this: -

[image]

Ignoring the negative sign is done quite often and this slightly corrupt act is also seen in magnetics (V = L.di/dt) instead of the version with a negative sign.

Answer (score 2):

The correct expression is the first one

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential
```

You use the second one only if you just care of the absolute value.